# How would I hide the slide deck on every page except the index page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

DEMO URL: http://epecho.com/tst/index.html

I would like to hide the slide deck on every page except the index page.
I have tried hiding it using $("#slidersection").hide(); as a test but it tentds to garment or break the slider. I would like to targed all page to hide the slide deck but leave it visible on the home page. Can this be done? I believe the slide deck takes it's size from its parent element upon loading.

in the above demo all is working but the hiding of the demo on every page.

Comment: That will be better if you take care of it on the server-side

Comment: I am using jQuery to hide and show the slid deck. Server side? I would have know clue where to start.

Answer (score 1):

change the css for the slide to be display:none; for default and then on the one page you do want it to start at in document.ready just do $("#slidersection").show();

or if want to add to overall js file only:

```
var url = document.location.href; 
if (url == 'http://epecho.com/tst/index.html') { $("#sliderSection").show(); }
```

Comment: so inside the doc ready block I would put something like this?:

if ("index.html") {
    $("#sliderSection").show();
}

Comment: you have a separate file called index.html right? so right inside that document in your header put a document.ready function and inside just put $("#sliderSection").show(); so it will only apply to that page

Comment: or if you want to do this just within ur overall javascript file see edit

Comment: No it dose not work, it's when the slider is hidden at the on set of initialization that is causing the problem. It brakes the slider in suggestions? Fire bug tells me that the dl.slider and the #slidedeckFrame have a height of 300px after initialization

Comment: or in ur css file add dl.slider{height:300px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
if (window.location !== 'http://epecho.com/tst/index.html')
{
    $('#slidedeckFrame').hide();
}
```

That worked for me.